# pop() is not working properly

Tags: c++, class

Here is a c++ code on stack.Ignore the extra code here

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class mystack
{
    private:
        int top;
        int size;
        int * s;
    public:
        void initialize()
        {
            top=-1;
            cin>>size;
            s=new int[size];
        }   
        ~mystack(){delete [] s;}
        void push()
        {
            int x;
            if(top==size-1)
                cout<<"stack overflow!"<<endl;
            else
            {
                cout<<"Enter element to be pushed:";
                cin>>x;
                top++;
                s[top]=x;
                cout<<s[top]<<endl;
            }
        }   
        int pop()
        {
            int p=s[top];
            if(top==-1)
                return 0;
            else
            {
                top--;
                return p;
            }
        }
        int maxsize()
        {
            return size;
        }
        int isempty()
        {
            if(top==-1)
                return 0;
            else
                return 1;
        }
        void display()
        {
            int i,p=top;
            cout<<s[0]<<endl;
            for(i=0;i<=p;i++)
                cout<<s[i]<<endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    cout<<"Enter no. of stacks:";
    cin>>n;
    mystack * st=new mystack[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter size of stack "<<i+1<<":";
        st[i].initialize();
    }
    int c,s;
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"*****Operations*****"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.Push 2.Pop 3.Maxsize 4.isempty 5.Display 6.Quit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter your choice:";
        cin>>c;
        if(n>1)
        {
            cout<<"Operation on which stack:";
            cin>>s;
        }
        else
            s=1;
        if(c==1)
            st[s-1].push();
        else if(c==2)
        {
            if(st[s-1].pop()==0)
                cout<<"stack underflow!"<<endl;
            else
                cout<<st[s-1].pop()<<endl;
        }
        else if(c==3)
            cout<<st[s-1].maxsize()<<endl;
        else if(c==4)
        {
            if(st[s-1].isempty()==0)
                cout<<"True"<<endl;
            else
                cout<<"False"<<endl;
        }
        else if(c==5)
            st[s-1].display();
        else if(c==6)
            break;
        else
        {
            cout<<"Wrong input!"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Here accessing pop operation gives the element of top-1.I can't understand why.What should I do?When I do return s[top--] same thing is happening.

Comment: I would suggest solving the problem with 1 stack and getting a better understanding of what your code is doing.

Comment: Some general suggestions: separate your input logic from your push / initialize / etc., check `top==-1` *before* the array access, and you should have a constructor that initializes things.

Comment: In here "top--; return p;" your should first save what you want to return and then decrement - according to your push. But read above suggestions first.

Comment: I single stepped through the code, and very quickly (<10 min) found the problem.  Please try the debugger, or add debug cerr statements with output directed to another tty,  Example:   yourPgm 2> /dev/pts/2

Comment: I forgot to give kudo's - the code compiled, it ran, and you have the one simple logic error ... but you might try typing quit into your command loop.  oofdah.

Comment: @crashmstr I've used a function initialize() here,it's working as constructor

Comment: @saptarshinag not the same thing. You still have uninitialized values for `top`, `size`, and `s` until you call that. You should still have a constructor that at least initializes to something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't gotten back to this, I am going to presume you've already found your logic error.

So here is the one error I found.  There may be more, I quit looking ...

In the following code, how many times is pop() being called?

```
  else if(c==2)
    {
        if(st[s-1].pop()==0)
            cout<<"stack underflow!"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<st[s-1].pop()<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: i.e. Do not use a stack-modifying action (pop) to detect underflow.  Instead, use a status check, like isempty().   Another test to consider:  what happens when user pushes 1, 2, 3, 0 into the same stack, then pop, pop, pop, pop, pop?

Comment: that's fine I'll correct it...but I think it's not the problem.When I pop why the element before top is being returned?

Comment: Why is the element before top being returned?  
When (c==2), there are 2 calls to pop() and should be only 1.

Comment: The first is in the if clause:   "if(st[s-1].pop()==0)"

The second is in the cout:       "cout<<st[s-1].pop()<<endl;"

Both are called when pop() does not return 0.  I suggest replace the 1st with "st[s-1].isempty()"